# Launch Unpublished WP8 app via NFC

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc

I am attempting to test launch my app that I am writting via NFC with windows phone 8.

According to the documentation I have seen, in order to do this you need the app ID.

From my experience you only get an app ID after you publish an app.

So that brings me to the question.

How do I launch an app via NFC tag that I programmed without knowledge of the App ID before hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to launch apps with NFC via URI association. You can register your app for an URI association, and it will be launched when receives a message with a URI of the registered protocol.

For example you can register the protocol `myapp`, by adding following code to the *WMAppManifest.xml* file:

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="myapp" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

That way, if the device receives a message with the URI `myapp:something`, the app will be started. This also allows the app to be launched from other app.

Find more information  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations).

If you still prefer the appID approach, for testing purposes you can use the `Product ID` property from *WMAppManifest.xml*, but note that it will replaced by other ID when published.